# How to bulk insert in ElasticSearch? (Pentaho Kettle is not working)

Tags: elasticsearch, kettle

I have an ETL process that I am implementing using Pentaho Kettle (Spoon). Everything is working fine, except that I can't insert the generated data into my ElasticSearch remote server.
I tried using Kettle's component "Elastic Search Bulk Insert", but Kettle can't find my Elastic Search nodes (as it can be seen [here](http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?162449-Perform-an-elastic-search-bulk-insert-in-a-remote-server)) .
Is there any reliable way to add a lot of information to my ES server? Solutions with kettle or independent scripts/plugins/etc are accepted, the only constraint is that The ETL process will run in a different machine from Elastic Search.
Kettle has a custom Java script element that could also be used.

EDIT: I found out that Pentaho is using a very old version of elastic search (0.16.3), I am trying to find a way to update it. No luck until now...

Comment: any luck with updating the jar files?

Comment: No, I didn't, but I tried years ago...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

elasticsearch is a RESTful search engine so i use the **REST Client kettle step**. All you have to do is to follow the rest standarts for insertion rows into your remote elasticsearch server. it works well.

Comment: How did you do that? Where should I reffer to?

Answer (score 2):

I changed the dependent jar from `elasticsearch-0.16.3.jar` to `elasticsearch-1.6.0.jar` (it also needs `lucene-core-4.10.4.jar`), copied 'ElasticSearchBulk' ([with some help](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/ElasticSearch+Bulk+Insert)) as a new plugin or modify the source code, because some of the locations of the elasticsearch package have changed (removing the wrong package import, then adding the correct). Finally, it is working well with elasticsearch1.6.

Comment: How did you do that? Please share what u did

Comment: @Nathan Tuggy If you could provide a tutorial, I would really appreciate it!

Comment: @Amir … the editing? Or the jar tweaking? I don't actually use elasticsearch, I just fixed up this post. (You may need to ask a new question and link to this for context. But don't just ask for a tutorial; ask for a solution to a particular problem you had trying to follow this answer.)

Comment: Jar Tweaking. I have figured it out using @mermerkaya's post. Thanks for checking!

Answer (score 1):

First you should know your Elastic Search Server configuration.
Open elasticsearch.yml file under your Elasticsearch server and copy IP Address, transport.tcp.port and cluster.name values.

Come back to your Kettle, open "ElasticSearch Bulk Insert" task.
Add "culster.name" in the [Settings] tab, and IP addres and tcp.port in [Servers] tab.
Then try "Test Connection". it should works.

Answer (score 1):

One common mistake in this context is copying elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar to \data-integration\lib. This is unnecessary and counterproductive.

Steps:

1. Servers:       localhost         9300
2. Settings:      cluster.name      my_cluster_name    // from elasticsearch.yml
3. PDI 8.2 or 8.3 or 9.0
4. Elasticsearch ver 6.4.2

Comment: Elasticsearch is now at version 7.12.  Pentaho's (ver 9.1) Elasticsearch Bulk Insert step does not seem to work with this version.  Any advice on how to get it to work?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Current PDI(6.0.1) release support elasticsearch 1.5.4,

if someone needs to latest elasticsearch 2.2 working plugin for PDI 6.*

U can download the it, I tested it working with 2.2

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0hgGtBdLOBMbWtfVVFnTE1uVmM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I can confirm this also worked for me. Would be nice if someone spelled out how to build it so we could reproduce.